# Issue with css background-size on svg with IE11

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser

I have a SVG image with CSS as follows:

```
background: url("/assets/img/image1.svg") no-repeat center top scroll;
background-size: 100% auto
```

Styling works fine in all other browsers except **Internet Explorer 11**. I did some investigation which ends up resulting, we should add `height` and `width` in `SVG`.

My question: If we add those `height` and `width` attributes, will the image be still scalable and responsive in all other browsers and devices? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615336/background-size-cover-ie11-not-covering-full-area?

Comment: Nope , It should have work responsively .

Comment: @tatranskymedved : May I know, why this question down voted as "off topic" ? Are the CSS question aren't related to programming!!

Comment: Very detailed explanation at https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

Comment: @mayank Sorry, I'm not the one that down-voted the question. IMO the negative vote was set for unnecessary sentences (like "You've guessed it.......... it is IE 11"). Next time you should avoid such phrases and go straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this property break it in IE
`background: url("/assets/img/image1.svg") no-repeat center top scroll;`
Try to put the properties individually like that:

```
background-image: url('/assets/img/image1.svg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-size: 100% auto;
```

ps. `background-attachment: scroll` I'm not sure if you really need that.

Comment: Doesn't help, and scroll is require

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is one of these properties, try to debug on IE and remove from the inspect 1 by 1 the properties.

Answer (score 0):

"If we add those height and width attributes, will the image be still scalable and responsive in all other browsers and devices?"

Yes! The image will scale based off of the CSS you provided. If you look at the source for the SVG I used `https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg` you'll see that `width="612px"` and `height="502.174px"` but with `background-size: 100% auto;` being set the you can see that the SVG is the same width of the element (50px) and the height is dynamic (or auto).

```css
div {
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    
    
    /* the only change below is the url source */
    background: url("https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg") no-repeat center top scroll; 
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to **MDN** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio you should use the **preserveAspectRatio** attribute and set it to none.

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20px" height="20px">...</svg>
```

Note: This will not work if the viewBox attribute is not present